# Can you upload a saved profile to Google Plus?

Tags: google-plus, profile

Using Takeout, you can download your Google Plus profile information to a json file.
Is it possible to use this file to upload the information to a new Google Plus account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. Takeout links with your Google+ account, but Google+ does not has any connection with Takeout.

Google+ does has an API, but there is absolutely no way any API would ever allow an app to alter it's user personal details.

Also, a single person creating and using multiple accounts, or someone creating an account with the exact details of an another account is something no company had ever wanted.